# How to edit a name on screen2 and make the new name appear on screen1?

Tags: flutter, dart

I started studying Flutter these days and I made the app of this [tutorial](https://codelabs.flutter-io.cn/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/index.html#0) smoothly.

I managed to create a button that switch from list and card visualization, an icon that removes a word and instead of showing infinite words now shows only 20 words. But now I wanted to create another screen via named routes and on this screen you can edit the name you clicked on screen1, for example:

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

But I'm having a lot of trouble trying to do this. I managed to create the screen2, the textform and the routes but the part of changing the name is still giving me little headaches xD

Could someone help me please? This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Names',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const RandomWords(),
        EditScreen.routeName: (context) => EditScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandomWords({super.key});

  @override
  State<RandomWords> createState() => _RandomWordsState();
}

class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final _saved = <WordPair>{};
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 20);
  String selected = '';
  bool isList = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Startup Names'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_border_sharp),
              onPressed: _pushSaved,
              tooltip: 'Favorites',
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon:
                  isList ? const Icon(Icons.grid_view) : const Icon(Icons.list),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isList = !isList;
                });
              },
              tooltip: isList ? 'Card mode' : 'List mode',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: isList ? lista() : cards());
  }

  Widget lista() {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemCount: 40,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return const Divider();

        final index = i ~/ 2;
        if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
        }

        return favorites(_suggestions[index], index);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget cards() {
    return GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemCount: 20,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
            mainAxisExtent: 100),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          if (i >= _suggestions.length) {
            _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
          }

          return Card(child: favorites(_suggestions[i], i));
        });
  }

  Widget favorites(WordPair pair, int index) {
    final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          pair.asPascalCase,
          style: _biggerFont,
        ),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
              color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
              tooltip: alreadySaved ? 'Remove favorite' : 'Favorite',
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (alreadySaved) {
                    _saved.remove(pair);
                  } else {
                    _saved.add(pair);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              color: Colors.black87,
              tooltip: 'Remove from list',
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _suggestions.remove(pair);
                  _saved.remove(pair);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () {
          selected = pair.asPascalCase;
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second',
              arguments: Argumentos(index, selected));
        });
  }

  void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (context) {
          final tiles = _saved.map(
            (pair) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  pair.asPascalCase,
                  style: _biggerFont,
                ),
              );
            },
          );

          final divided = tiles.isNotEmpty
              ? ListTile.divideTiles(
                  context: context,
                  tiles: tiles,
                ).toList()
              : <Widget>[];

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Favorites'),
            ),
            body: ListView(children: divided),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EditScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/second';
  const EditScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<EditScreen> createState() => _EditScreenState();
}

class _EditScreenState extends State<EditScreen> {
  final first = TextEditingController();
  final second = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final argumentos = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Argumentos;
    String selected = argumentos.name;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Edit word'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text("What's the new name?",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100, vertical: 16),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: first,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'First part of the name',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100, vertical: 16),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: second,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Second part of the name',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Change it'),
                onPressed: () {
                  selected = (WordPair(first.text, second.text)).toString();
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Argumentos {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Argumentos(this.id, this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .then() and update value.

Exp :

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second',
    arguments: Argumentos(index, selected)).then((value) {
    setState(() { // update ui
    // update value here;    
    });});
```

then() : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html

Comment: Hmmm, still don't work or maybe because I still don't know how to use .then() and value. I tried to put _suggestions[index] = WordPair(selected, selected); inside of the "//update value here;" just to test and I noticed that it duplicates the name, so maybe if I put _suggestions[index] = WordPair(first.text, second.text) it could work, but instead it gives me this error: Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'first', the same for 'second'. Could you help me how to make it work?